# Are the placement of indicies of the $\mathfrak{so}(3, \mathbb{R})$ Lie Algebra structure constants 'irrelevant'?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

I have been learning about the $SO(3)$ symmetry group in my physics classes, and it is often asserted in books that the structure constants of the Lie algebra behave just as indices do in Euclidean space where one can largely ignore the distinction between vectors and co-vectors. However because the structure constants are basis dependant this seems impossible unless one picks a particular basis. However in the canonical basis most use:

\begin{equation}\begin{array}{ccc}
L_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
&L_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
&L_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

We have the positive definite metric induced from the Killing form:
$$
g_{ij}=-\mathrm{Tr}(L_iL_j)=2\delta_{ij}
$$
Which is not Euclidean. This means that while the $c$ below are all $1$, $0$, or $-1$
$$
[L_i, L_j]=c_{ij}^{\>\>\>k}L_k
$$
the lowered structure constants cannot be merely $c_{ijk} = \varepsilon_{ijk}$ where $\varepsilon$ is the Levi-Civita Tensor

In fact the lowered structure constants would have to be twice the Levi-Civita Tensor.

Have I made an error? Does it have to do with Levi-Civita tensor in fact being a Tensor Density? If not, why do physicists insist it makes no difference, when it clearly changes the constants?

Comment: I guess you're right. Possibly they prefer write with a suitable scalar multiple of the Killing form.

Comment: As a general matter, dropping the distinction between upper/lower indices only makes sense when restricting attention to *orthonormal* bases. Also, tensor densities aren't involved here, since everything is linear; it's just that a suitably oriented basis must be chosen to avoid a minus sign.

Comment: Thank you both. This was my understanding as well, the physicist solution seems to be to avoid all the piled up constants by stuffing them into either the group parameters (which causes, say, radians, to lose their immediate physical meaning) or stuff them into coupling constants of the lagrangian, which is better, but still less than clear.